# react.js: prevent logic in jsx and move render out of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1. JSX lets you inline Javascript logic/function calls. Is there any way to prevent this? This would force the developer to move the logic out of `jsx`, and add the 'computed' properties to `this.state` in `componentWillUpdate`.
2. I would also like to move `render` out of the `component` altogether, so it only has access to `props` and `state`, and doesn't have access to `this`. In terms of implementation, `component` would publish an event with `{props: this.props, state: this.state}` as the data, and the event bus executes the corresponding `render`.

Is there any existing way to accomplish these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I use React Templates (http://wix.github.io/react-templates/). I find the separation of logic/presentation very useful as is more easy to work with graphic designers in my team (they like to build the markup by themselves).

Although you can still use javascript logic in the templates, is very inconvenient, and you are forced to think in helper methods in your component, which is more clean in my opinion because all the logic is in the component's code.

Have a look at it.

Comment: I don't like the angular style custom attributes, but will take a look at their implementation. Ty!